# Babel does not transpile with ES2015 but Stage0 preset

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm running into a problem transpiling the following code (redux reducer) with babel and the ES2015 preset. I'm (wrongly) assuming this is code that can be transpiled.

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
        return state.map(todo =>
            (todo.id === action.id)
                ? {
                ...todo,
                completed: !todo.completed
                }
                : todo
            )

        default:
        return state
    }
}

export default todos
```

The error message

```
repl: Unexpected token (7:16)
   5 |             (todo.id === action.id)
   6 |                 ? {
>  7 |                 ...todo,
```

Transpiling with the Stage0 preset works fine. I did verify this behaivor with the [Babel online](https://babeljs.io/repl/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `preset-2016` doesn't support object rest spread. It's stage 3 now

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was indeed the problem. I am still wondering why my coworker is able to transpile this with babel default preset and I need to set this explicitly

Comment: I think he's using it in development but you're trying to create production build. Is it true?

Comment: Nope, we both used ```babel src --out-file index.js --source-maps``` with version 6.26.0 to transpile the file in question. We did this to share code between mobile and web app in a private module because of problems with the webpack setup when using npm link and symlinks. Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [object spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) operator which is part of stage 3.